# Rolling Flat File Log File not rolling properly

Tags: file, logging, enterprise-library

I'm using Microsoft Enterprise 5 Logging block. While testing locally all rolling flat files are created correctly and Database logging to my local instance of SQL logs as expected. The problem is when I publish my apps to the Test environment we have. Here it's when something strange happens: Logs files are created with strange GUID-like names.They eventually roll but it is very strange and it does that often. Also Databse logging does not happen either. I have not been able to find anything related to this issue online. I suspect Authentication issues when setting the App Pools and Folders in IIS but not sure. 
Does anyone has this problem?
Here's my configuration settings:

```xml
<add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="D:\logs\MobileApps\rolling.log" formatter="Text Formatter"
        rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Hour" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd-hh" />
```

Files get names like

```
deb7f413-6cb3-44ac-900e-02883856e82bRolling.log
rolling.2012-01-19-09.log
```

Answer (score 3):

The **RollingFlatFileListener** is based on the the .NET Framework's **TextWriterTraceListener**, which defines this prefixing behavior: "*If an attempt is made to write to a file that is in use or unavailable, the file name is automatically prefixed by a GUID*."

You can either define your own trace listener that doesn't keep the file open (for guidance on how to write custom trace listeners see Lab 2 of the [set of hands-on labs on EntLib extensibility](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13738)), or use the [distributor service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664428%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) and write to the file in a single place; for the latter you'll need to set up MSMQ.

Comment: very odd behavior to be honest.

Comment: So you answer is "Intended Behavior, won't fix".  So how hard would it be to write a multi-threaded aware listener?

Comment: Actually, switched to Log4Net, and this issue is gone.  However, the log4net rolling log doesn't prune old files, so had to extend that - much easier.